# PDFTK - and the ability to change the default view

Tags: view, default, zooming, pdftk

I have been merging PDFs using PDFTK with great success, the pages that are used to generate the pdf are set to 'click to show one page at a time' (basically the whole of the first page is displayed when the pdf opens, based on the height of the page).

however the generated pdf defaults back to filling the reader based on its width (not all the first page shows).

Do you know a way of controlling the view of the generated pdf? because I would prefer the whole page to be displayed based on its height?

Best regards

Daniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Daniel,

Thank you for your message.  When using pdftk to assemble a new PDF from PDF pages or documents (via the *cat* operation), the new PDF does not have display settings.  So the resulting PDF is displayed using the defaults set in your viewer's preferences.  Pdftk doesn't have a means of setting the display mode, but I will add that to the feature wishlist.  Meanwhile, you can change your Reader/Acrobat preferences to your preferred view mode as a workaround.

Regards-

Sid Steward

Pdftk Maintainer

Comment: Thank you very much Sid, Your tool has been a the back bone of a lot of my projects and I am very very pleased with the way that it performs.

Comment: Sid - I see this post is 3 years old, so I am wondering if this feature has been already added to the current version of the tool. Please advise.

Comment: It has not been added as of `pdftk-2.02`.

Comment: (As another appreciative `pdftk` user), I'm also hoping for this feature in a future `pdftk` version from the command line.   For Windows users, the gratis (but not libre) program PDF X-Change Lite allows setting a PDF's initial view on its free tier.